# Verilog - initializing register to high impedance?

Tags: verilog, simulation, hdl, quartus

The following code attempts to initialize register `output_reg` to high impedance, thereafter setting it to `1` on the positive edge of `clk`.

```
module test(
    input clk,
    output out,
    output reg output_reg
);

    assign out = output_reg;

    initial
        begin
            output_reg <= 1'bz;
        end

    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            output_reg <= 1'b1;
        end

endmodule
```

However, the simulation (Altera Quartus 9.1) shows the `output_reg` as being **initialized** to `1`, not `z`.

[image]

I have no idea why the `always` block sort of overrides the `initial` block.

**Note:** If I remove the `always` block, then the register initializes to `z`.

Comment: Can you add `\`timescale 1ns / 1ps` to module `test` and test again? (add it at first line of module, before `module test( ... `.

Comment: Added it, but it is exactly the same as before

Comment: There's a reason why Altera largely discontinued support for the Quartus simulator after 9.1. If you want to use the waveform editor, I'd recommend updating to 13.1, which both supports older devices, and uses ModelSim as a backend for the waveform simulator instead of the (flawed) Quartus simulator.

Comment: I would normally control high impedance with a drive or enable signal: `assign out = (drive) ? out_reg: 1'bz`

Comment: Have you tried `blocking` assignment instead of `non-blocking`? `=` instead of `<=`.

Comment: No I didn't, but why would it be different? There is only one assignment in each block.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of race condition. here, the second block is overriding over first, or you can say the first block is executing @0ns, but second block is @0.00...01ns. Normally you cant assign the value to same pin/port in multiple procedural block.